# Acquiring the templated type of a derived struct element of a base class vector

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have a vector which is a `std::unique_ptr` of my base struct `TextElBaseParams`. The elements of this vector consist of structs which are templated `TextElParams<T>`, these are derived from `TextElBaseParams`. The derived struct contains a pointer to a variable of type T named `var`.

I have a function which can only accept `TextElParams<T>`. I am unable to pass elements from the vector of `TextElBaseParams` to this function for obvious reasons, so I have the idea that I can somehow convert these elements back to their "derived" type before passing them to the function.

Is this the right way to go about it? If so, what would be the simplest way to implement this? If not, what alternatives could I use to solve this problem?

I am using SFML but the only things to do with that here are irrelevant. Here is a basic outline of my code:

```
struct TextElBaseParams {

};

template <typename T> struct TextElParams : public TextElBaseParams {
     TextElParams( std::string _font = "",
                   std::string _str = "",
                   int _fontSize = 1,
                   sf::Vector2f _position = {0,0},
                   T *_var = nullptr ) :
                   font{_font}, str{_str}, fontSize{_fontSize},
                   position{_position}, var{_var} {}

    std::string font;
    std::string str;
    int fontSize;
    sf::Vector2f position;
    T *var;
};
```

I attempt to call a function `addElement` which takes the `TextElParams<T>` argument:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TextElBaseParams>> tParamsVec; //Filled with derived elements

for(unsigned int i=0; i<tParamsVec.size(); ++i)
        addElement(*tParamsVec.at(i));
```

Prototype for the `addElement` function:

```
template<class T>
void addElement(TextElParams<T> &tParams);
```

`addElement` works if you directly feed it a `TextElParams<T>` struct.

Comment: If you have functions that only take the derived class... what's the purpose of the base class?

Comment: To avoid having multiple std::vectors for different template types of TextElParams<T>.

Answer (score 0):

That's what virtual functions are for. Make a virtual function in a base class and override it in derived classes. Now if you call a function via the pointer to base class, the corresponding derived function is called. See the example:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void invoke() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Derived;

template<typename T>
void func(Derived<T>& arg) {
    std::cerr << "called func with type " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    // do smth with arg
}

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void invoke() override {
        func(*this);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec;

    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived<int>>());
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived<double>>());
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived<void>>());

    for (const auto& t: vec) {
        t->invoke();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
called func with type i
called func with type d
called func with type v
```